# Scrolling UITableview bottom row to top position

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, xcode5

In one tableView I have 4 rows on section0 and 3 rows on section1. If I tap the row at indexPath (1,2) another row appears with a UIPickerView inside it. I want the tableView to scroll so that the pickerView moves at the top of the screen. To do that I implemented

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

but this only scrolls it up a little bit, not much.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, that's embarasing. As it so happens you do not need the above code to be between

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

...

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I'm gonna leave the answer here in case somebody has the same issue.